# Semantics of sys:locale

Tags: alfresco

The data dictionary pretty much forces every node in Alfresco to have a `sys:locale` value:

```xml
  <type name="sys:base">                                                                                                            
     <title>Base</title>                                                                                                            
     <mandatory-aspects>                                                                                                            
        <aspect>sys:referenceable</aspect>                                                                                          
        <aspect>sys:localized</aspect>                                                                                              
     </mandatory-aspects>                                                                                                           
  </type>  

  <!--                                                                                                                              
     Localization:                                                                                                                  
     If you add this aspect to a node, then the server will assume that all non-multilingual                                        
     properties apply to this locale.                                                                                               
  -->                                                                                                                               
  <aspect name="sys:localized">                                                                                                     
     <title>Translation</title>                                                                                                     
     <properties>                                                                                                                   
        <property name="sys:locale">                                                                                                
           <title>Locale</title>                                                                                                    
           <type>d:locale</type>                                                                                                    
           <mandatory>true</mandatory>                                                                                              
        </property>                                                                                                                 
     </properties>                                                                                                                  
  </aspect>
```

I can imagine a whole lot of content where a locale does not make sense to me at all. Images, video, sound, code are a few examples. I would guess this locale is used for indexing tokenized string type properties. Still, I cannot see how that makes sense in the context of the content mentioned.

What exactly are the semantics of `sys:locale` and how is it used by Alfresco ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sys:locale` serves as a fallback for the locale from the ContentData during indexing (if not set), so both `@cm:content.locale` and the tokenisation of `d:content` / `d:text` properties may / will be affected. In addition, `sys:locale` is used to differentiate the translations within the context of MultilingualContentService. On a site node, it affects the generated workflow descriptions for invitations.

`sys:locale` is not a real property in the sense that it is maintained in `alf_node_properties` - it is a virtual property much like `sys:uuid` derived from `alf_node` directly, which is why it affects even the content where it might not make much sense (apart from `d:text` property tokenization).

Comment: What you are saying may be true. But honestly, I don't see how this all makes sense and not end up in user confusion. I am looking at all nodes of a  repo and see all sorts  of @cm:content.locale + sys:locale combinations. Regarding locales in general, even the browser locale and the OS locale come into play for index/search. I would appreciate it a lot if somebody could explain.

Comment: The locale from the content URL always reflects the browser locale of the uploader. The `sys:locale` of the node typically reflects the browser locale of the user who created the node. Someone uploading a new version of content with a different locale will create these combinations. In case no locale is provided by the browser, the JVM locale is used (which is the same as the OS locale if not set explicitly via `-D` flags).
AFAIK indexing / searching only ever uses the JVM (OS) locale when no locale has been provided by the browser, via `sys:locale` or the content URL.

Comment: I guess you are right. Still I wonder who on earth expects this kind  of behavior. So, basically you are saying that if I want my german document indexed according to german rules, 1.) I need to make sure the guy who puts it into the system uses a german browser locale and  2.) I use the german browser locale when executing the search, right  ?  And no matter what, locale dependent tokenization and stemming somehow come into play unless I hack the contentmodel to disable that ?

Comment: In Lucene you were able to specify the multi-lingual analysis mode to be used for indexing / search. This helped to deal with users of different languages, i.e. even if someone uploaded a content in German it could be indexed in other locales too. And even if someone searched in English, it would find matches in German too, processing the query fragments in both English and German (and other locales). I have not found a way to configure this in SOLR yet, expect coding it into the search parameters...

Comment: Even if on top of all, you would hack the system to use a set of  locales for indexing and/or searching, that would make matters even more opaque and complicated.